# Visual Studio Code comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

When i go to **file --> toggle line comment(Ctrl + /)** or **file(Ctrl + Shift + /) --> toggle block comment** both show like this: `<!--  -->`, how can i use single line comment like //blabla? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the file type, this is how the comment should be done. If the file is an .html file, the comment will be made with `<!-- -->`. If your file is .ts, .js, .java, .cs, or other types, the comment must be with `//` or `/* */`.

Check the type of your file and then verify if the comments in the file are being made as the documentation shows.

What is the type of your file?

Comment: Help a lot, thank you